# Interface boundary conditions of superconductor

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity, boundary-conditions

Are the usual interface conditions for electromagnetic fields, i.e.
$$\mathbf{n}_{12}\times(\mathbf{E}_1-\mathbf{E}_2) = 0,$$
$$\mathbf{n}_{12}\bullet(\mathbf{D}_1-\mathbf{D}_2) = \sigma_s,$$
$$\mathbf{n}_{12}\bullet(\mathbf{B}_1-\mathbf{B}_2) = 0,$$
$$\mathbf{n}_{12}\times(\mathbf{H}_1-\mathbf{H}_2) = \mathbf{J}_s, $$
valid at the interface if one of the media is a superconductor? I would assume that they are since they are derived from Maxwell's equations. Is this correct?

Comment: It depends on what scale we are talking about here. Do you care about penetration depth? If not, then astroAmature is correct, and you can take magnetic field zero everywhere. If you do care about skin effect, it is more complicated

Answer (score 1):

Magnetic field is expelled from a superconductor by the [Meissner effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect), so the normal magnetic field goes to zero at the surface. For a type-I superconductor, a strong enough magnetic field will destroy the superconducting state. In a type-II superconductor a partial magnetic field can penetrate.

Comment: The Meissner effect says that the magnetic field decays exponentially into the superconductor, so the normal component of the magnetic field should still be continuous at the interface, shouldn't it?

Comment: @ECA18, the London penetration depth is small for most superconductors (around the order of a few hundred nm), so the surface current quickly cancels the internal field. A superconductor acts like a nearly perfect diamagnetic material.